# Regex on large array

Tags: regex, jedit

I have a very large string in the form:

```
a1 + b1
a2 + b2
a3 + b3
.
.
.
an + bn
```

and I need to convert it to C array operations:

```
a[1]+b[1];
a[2]+a[2];
.
.
.
a[n]+b[n];
```

What regular expression are you suggesting and which tool? 
I was trying the regular expressions of jedit but I can switch if required.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You cannot use regular expressions on an array, only on its members if they are strings. Perhaps you mean you have a very large string that you would like to modify?

Comment: Exactly, I will modify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jEdit:

search for:

```
([a-z]+)([0-9]+)
```

replace with:

```
$1[$2]
```